# mkfs + any solution for “could not read block” or disk replacing

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, ext4, fsck, mkfs

we doing `mkfs` on the disk `sda` as the following

```
mkfs.ext4  -j -m 0 /dev/sda -F



mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Warning: could not erase sector 2: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
122101760 inodes, 488378646 blocks
0 blocks (0.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=2636120064
14905 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848

 

Allocating group tables: done
Warning: could not read block 0: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:     0/14905
Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.
```

actually file-system not created and we can see it from `lsblk -f`

```
lsblk -f
NAME               FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
```

so from mkfs the warning are

```
Allocating group tables: done
Warning: could not read block 0: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:     0/14905
Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.
```

any chance to do some bybass or some workaround in order to create the file system on `sda` disk ?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for relevant information.

Comment: finally -   we replaced the disk